# Change Default Tab Heading Text | Wordpress WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In wordpress woocommerce under single product page, i want to change the default tab headings:

**Change "Description" to Features** and 
**Change "Additional Information" to "Specifications"**

Under which PHP file should i make these changes, for it to take effect ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would rename the tabs (just add to your theme `functions.php` file) - This is valid for older versions of WooCommerce [per their documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/editing-product-data-tabs/):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_rename_tabs', 98 );
function woo_rename_tabs( $tabs ) {

    $tabs['description']['title'] = __( 'Features' );       // Rename the description tab
    $tabs['additional_information']['title'] = __( 'Specifications' );  // Rename the additional information tab

    return $tabs;

}
```

Comment: It breaks the site with WooCommerce 3.6.5